# extract-text-webpack-plugin removes all .js code

Tags: javascript, css, loader, webpack, stylus

TL;DR: when generating two .js and one .css chunks the plugin removes all .js code from one of the .js chunks.

This is repeatable behaviour even if I only use the examples from the webpack docs.

I may be missing something, but I can't find what it is :)

The config is as follows:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [
            './.build/app/app_dependencys.js',
            './.build/app/_helpers/api_helpers.js',
            './.build/app/event-manager.js',
            './.build/app/route_handlers/Router.js'
        ],
        lib: [
            'c3',
            'lodash',
            'moment',
            'moment-timezone',
            'pleasejs',
            'react-bootstrap-datetimepicker',
            'react',
            'react-bootstrap',
            'react-d3-components',
            'react-datepicker-component',
            'react-googlemaps',
            'react-router',
            'react-slider',
            'reactable',
            'select2'
        ],
        css: glob.sync('./css/css/*.styl')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'js/dist'),
        filename: "app.js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel?compact=false', ignore: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json"},
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('raw', 'raw!stylus')
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('id', "./../../css/compiled/css.css", {allChunks: false}),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"lib", /* filename= */"lib.js", Infinity)
    ],
    externals: ['jquery'],
    bail: true
};
```

When running `webpack`, this is the output:

```
Time: 51884ms
                       Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                      app.js   3.8 kB    0, 1  [emitted]  app, css
                      lib.js  3.47 MB       2  [emitted]  lib
./../../css/compiled/css.css   131 kB       1  [emitted]  css
   [0] multi app 64 bytes {0} [built]
   [0] multi css 364 bytes {1} [built]
   [0] multi lib 196 bytes {2} [built]
    + 634 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 1 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 1 hidden modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
        + 1 hidden modules

.... it goes on for a while ...
```

As a result:

- `css.css` contains all css, as required
- `lib.js` contains all lib code, as required
- `app.js`: every single entry in app.js is replaced with

  ```
  /***/ 581:
  /***/ function(module, exports) {

      // removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

  /***/ },

  /***/ 582:
  /***/ function(module, exports) {

          // removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

  /***/ },
  ...
  ```

Reported to the plugin authors as well: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/118

Comment: I just started running into this as I was moving my webpack files to a lower level in my application hierarchy. Did you ever make any headway on this?

Comment: Nope :( There's also almost no headway in the issue either

Comment: You could try some of the suggestions posted there: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/118#issuecomment-213582249, https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/118#issuecomment-223678580, https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/118#issuecomment-223689905

Answer (score 0):

answer here:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/118

> Okay, what worked for me is: good: entry: { js: './js/app.js', css:
>   './scss/main.scss' }, bad: entry: { js: './js/app.js', scss:
>   './scss/main.scss' } the only difference - css key instead of scss.
>   And also entry: [ './js/main.js', './scss/main.scss' ], works too.

Comment: You should give more info, a link is good as comment not as answer. Please provide something more